# Retrieving Velocity loop variables in JavaScript

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, templates, velocity

I had one change Password page where i am entering the current password,change password this will send to back-end and in back-end i am doing some process and throwing list of 3 error if password related criteria doesn't match. In the below code i am storing the all 3 errors in **changePasswordError** object , with help of velocity foreach loop i am storing into loop variables named as e.

this is the foreach loop of velocity ,here in changePasswordError im storing all the errors and storing into loopvariable e.

```
#foreach( $e in $errors.get("changePasswordError") )
   <div class="ui-state-error" >$e</div>
            <br/>
   #end
```

I want to display this loopvariable e to get into javascript.How i can achieve this?

```
<script>    
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#loginDlg1").before('  
            <div class="ui-state-error" >
        //wanted to show the error message e here...how i can display here                
        </div>
        ');
  });
</script>
```

Any help will be appreciated.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

ok, finally i am able to get the loopvariable into javascript with the help of set directive of the velocity template.

Below is the solution

```
#foreach( $e in $errors.get("changePasswordError") )
        #set ($editAttr=$e) // here im setting the loopvariable e into temp variable editAttr
   #end
     <script>   
            $(document).ready(function(){
            var v = "$editAttr"; // by this i am able to retrieve in javascript.
            alert("$editAttr"); // or if i want to alert directly the velocity elements into javascript then can able to alert like this

            $("#loginDlg1").before('<div class="ui-state-error">$editAttr</div>');
        });
    </script>
```